# Penetration testing of Angular JS application in ZAP or Burp Suite

Tags: testing, penetration-testing, zap, burp, penetration-tools

I am struggling to test Angular JS application, Can someone provide me reference to learn that, Couldnt find any.

I want to attack the application but it seems not all links are being visited by Crawler.

Comment: Burp Spider has limited support for Ajax. To get a thorough test using Burp you'll need to do a manual crawl, then use Scanner.

Answer (score 1):

How are you exploring the application?

In ZAP you should use the Ajax Spider as this will launch browsers in order to explore it. The standard spider will not be as effective.

Comment: Can you share any reference to learn in depth ? I have assignment to complete. :(